# Type Error 'module' is not callable - how to fix?

Tags: python, conda

I have checked other questions similar but they are not working. I'm trying to run the following code:

```
# Create the images

for n in progressbar(range(count)):
    
    # Set image name
    image_name = str(n).zfill(zfill_count) + '.png'
    
    # Get a random set of valid traits based on rarity weights
    trait_sets, trait_paths = generate_trait_set_from_config()
    # Generate the actual image
    generate_single_image(trait_paths, os.path.join(op_path, image_name))
    
    # Populate the rarity table with metadata of newly created image
    for idx, trait in enumerate(trait_sets):
        if trait is not None:
            rarity_table[CONFIG[idx]['name']].append(trait[: -1 * len('.png')])
        else:
            rarity_table[CONFIG[idx]['name']].append('none')**
```

I'm getting the error over the line "for n in progressbar". I've seen references that maybe I have multiple files named the same but I can't find them.

Comment: What is your import for progressbar?

Comment: `progressbar()` is some sort of function or module can you share what lib this is?

Comment: Where does `progressbar` come from? Is it an import?

Comment: is it https://pypi.org/project/progressbar/?

Comment: from conda I have ran both "pip install Pillow pandas progressbar2" and pip install progressbar

Comment: dont install both versions, you can only use or `progressbar` or `progressbar2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only `progressbar2` can be used without a instance

```sh
pip uninstall progressbar
pip install progressbar2
```

sample code

```py
import time
from progressbar import progressbar

for i in progressbar(range(100)):
    time.sleep(0.02)
```